# localizing date in asp.net to different locales

Tags: .net, localization

how to localize date in asp.net

I want to localize date 10/12/2011 in fr-FR etc....

I wamt to read the date from xml and write to Excel cell based on localization.

Thank you
Ramesh.T.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht77y576.aspx